# Setting up ejabberd via websockets

Tags: websocket, ejabberd

I have an **ejabberd** server up and running. 
I can test it via [web clients](http://conversejs.org) and it works fine using BOSH connections.

I would like to connect to it via web sockets now, and I am not sure what I am missing for it to work, I just know it doesn't.

Here is an extract from my **ejabberd.yml**

```
    hosts:
     - "localhost"
     - "somedomain.com"
     - "im.somedomain.com"

listen : 
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    ## register: true
    ## captcha: true
    tls: true
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
```

Now I tried to open a web socket via javascript as follows :

`var ws = new WebSocket("ws://somedomain:5280/websocket/");`

I get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in return. I have nothing within ejabberd's logs when I try to open a weksocket. I do have logs of the BOSH connections.

I am not sure if I am testing appropriately, nor if my server is setup correctly.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Connection timeout error will throw by the server when the client does not send **pong** response to the server make sure you are sending the pong response.If you are using Strophe.js kindly check Handlers http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.14/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.addHandler

```
    connection = new WebSocket("ws://somedomain:5280/websocket/");

//Adding ping handler using strophe connection
    connection.addHandler(pingHandler, "urn:xmpp:ping", "iq", "get");

//Ping Handler Call back function
    function pingHandler(ping) {
        var pingId = ping.getAttribute("id");
        var from = ping.getAttribute("from");
        var to = ping.getAttribute("to");
        var pong = strophe.$iq({
            type: "result",
            "to": from,
            id: pingId,
            "from": to
        });
        connection.send(pong);
        return true;
    }
```

Also, consider you are adding this configuration to your ejabberd.yml

```
websocket_ping_interval: 50
websocket_timeout: 60
```